# way to properly setup Laravel-echo authentication for private channels

Tags: laravel, socket.io, laravel-echo

I tried a lot but still can not setup properly LaravelEcho. Actually i unable to setup authentication step.The private channel are not authenticating. here is larave-echo CLI result

[image]

Boostrap.js

```
/**
 * Echo exposes an expressive API for subscribing to channels and listening
 * for events that are broadcast by Laravel. Echo and event broadcasting
 * allows your team to easily build robust real-time web applications.
 */

import Echo from "laravel-echo"

// window.Pusher = require('pusher-js');
window.io = require('socket.io-client');

window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'socket.io',
    host: 'http://localhost:6001'
});
```

Layout.blade.php

```
Echo.private('App.User.'+id)
                .notification((notification) => {
                    console.log(notification);
  });
```

laravel-echo-server.json

```
{
    "authHost": "http://bigplan.com",
    "authEndpoint": "/broadcasting/auth",
    "clients": [
        {
            "appId": "*********",
            "key": "*************************"
        }
    ],
    "database": "redis",
    "databaseConfig": {
        "redis": {
            "port": "6379",
            "host": "localhost"
        },
        "sqlite": {
            "databasePath": "/database/laravel-echo-server.sqlite"
        }
    },
    "devMode": false,
    "host": "localhost",
    "port": "6001",
    "protocol": "http",
    "referrers": [],
    "sslCertPath": "",
    "sslKeyPath": "",
    "verifyAuthPath": true,
    "verifyAuthServer": false
}
```

Comment: In current iterations, Laravel always assumes it's listening on `App.Events.`, so it's currently listening on `App.Events.App.User` .To fix this, prefix your custom namespace with a `.`, such as this: `'.App.User.'+id`

Answer (score 0):

You might be missing the routes to authenticate, by default it's located in routes/channel.php. The broadcast callback should return true if it's authenticated.

Here is an example :

```
Broadcast::channel('notify.{employeeId}', function ($user, $employeeId) {

    $employee = $user->employee;

    if (!$employee){
        return false;
    }

    return $employee->id==$employeeId;

});
```

`notify.{employeeId}` is your private channel name that you have defined in your Event class/

`$employeeId` here is the one that you send from echo client, it can be anything, in my case, it's employee ID.

`$user` is the current authenticated user.

Docs: 
https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/broadcasting#authorizing-channels